# Can a pin be on a state different from the reset state if the chip is erased?

Tags: stm32, firmware

I am working with the STM32F030CC and noticed that PA2 strangely has an internal pull-up resistor enabled when the chip is erased. The reset state of that pin is high-impedance input, and when I press the reset button, it goes back to that state. However, without pressing the reset button, the pin remains in pull-up mode.

I have tried using different chips and repeated the erase process multiple times, but on every occasion, the pull-up resistor gets configured.

The PCB doesn't have anything that's acting as the pull-up. The pin drives a NPN that is working fine on the normal application (and without any current leakage on the reset state as well).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it certainly can, and it also will be.

PA2 is the USART_TX pin, and the factory bootloader uses it in input pull-up mode.

And, when the F03CC MCU flash is erased, the MCU determines with an Empty Check feature that there is no valid firmware and runs the bootloader.

Comment: I forgot to consider the bootloader... Everything makes sense now thank you a lot!